# How to return a Jruby proc/block/closure to java and invoke it

Tags: jruby

I would like the ability to return blocks from an embedded jruby instance to regular java. My java code should be able to pass the required parameters (lets assume it knows the right arity) and then receive the result. Any samples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you can do direct embedding, use JavaEmbedUtils and either call eval on a string of ruby code that defines your proc/block/closure or have your ruby code implement an interface where certain methods return your proc/block/closure. Incredibly contrived example to sum two numbers below:

SampleApp.java

```
import org.jruby.Ruby;
import org.jruby.RubyRuntimeAdapter;
import org.jruby.RubyFixnum;
import org.jruby.RubyProc;
import org.jruby.javasupport.JavaEmbedUtils;
import org.jruby.runtime.Block;
import org.jruby.runtime.ThreadContext;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class SampleApp {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

                // Create runtime instance
                Ruby runtime = JavaEmbedUtils.initialize(new ArrayList());

                // Parameters
                RubyFixnum paramA = new RubyFixnum(runtime, 1);
                RubyFixnum paramB = new RubyFixnum(runtime, 2);

                // Runtime eval method
                RubyRuntimeAdapter evaler = JavaEmbedUtils.newRuntimeAdapter();
                RubyProc additionProcFromEval = (RubyProc)evaler.eval(runtime, "Proc.new { |a, b| a + b }");
                printProcResult(runtime, additionProcFromEval, paramA, paramB);

                // Interface implementation method
                SomeInterfaceImpl someImpl = new SomeInterfaceImpl();
                RubyProc additionProcFromInterface = (RubyProc)someImpl.getAdditionProc();
                printProcResult(runtime, additionProcFromInterface, paramA, paramB);

                // Shutdown and terminate instance
                JavaEmbedUtils.terminate(runtime);
        }

        protected static void printProcResult(Ruby runtime, RubyProc proc, RubyFixnum paramA, RubyFixnum paramB) {
                Block block = proc.getBlock();
                ThreadContext threadContext = ThreadContext.newContext(runtime);
                int result = (Integer)block.call(threadContext, paramA, paramB).toJava(new Integer(0).getClass());
                System.out.println("Result = " + result);
        }
}
```

SomeInterface.java

```
interface SomeInterface {
    org.jruby.RubyProc getAdditionProc();
}
```

SomeInterfaceImpl.rb

```rb
require 'java'
class SomeInterfaceImpl

        include Java::SomeInterface

        java_signature 'org.jruby.RubyProc getAdditionProc()'
        def getAdditionProc()
                return Proc.new { |a, b| a + b }
        end

end
```

And this is how you can test:

```sh
javac -classpath jruby.jar SomeInterface.java
jrubyc --javac -cp . SomeInterfaceImpl.rb
javac -cp jruby.jar:. SampleApp.java
java -cp jruby.jar:. SampleApp
```

References:

https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/DirectJRubyEmbedding

http://tommy.chheng.com/2010/06/20/call-a-jruby-method-from-java/

Comment: Thanx for the effort but you have made some assumptions, like assuming the proc is compatible with a java interface. I was after something more "dynamic" without the glue. I was hoping the runtime provided a helper or something that wrapped the Proc in some java object with a var args like java.lang.refl.Method.invoke() just works..